# Firefox Storage not updating

Tags: firefox, local-storage

Lately Firefox Storage tab in it's Web Dev tools is not working correctly for me. When there are changes in the localStorage, the data displayed in the tab doesn't update, not even when I refresh the page. For it to work, I have to close Web Dev tools and then reopen it.

I tried using a fresh install of Firefox without addons, tried both Linux and Windows, tried in virtual machine, and still won't work, so I'm guessing it must be due to some recent update.

To reproduce the problem:

- Go to any website
- Open Web Dev Tools (F12)
- Go to Storage tab
- Right click Local Storage file and delete all
- Refresh page to check if Storage updates

Anyone else having the same problem? Glad if anyone can help.

Comment: I confirm I encounter the same issue. Closing and repoening the dev tools does fix it for me, thanks for noticing !

Comment: Confirmed. Seeing this behavior as well.